# What are Chinese terms for 'androgynous', 'gender neutral', 'non binary' etc. to imply gender neutrality?

Tags: vocabulary, simplified-characters, colloquialisms, gender

I’m currently working on a textiles project for University inspired by Asian streetwear subculture and my main focus is androgyny and gender fluidity with the aim to create a collection of unisex/genderless clothing.

I was wondering if anyone knew the mandarin and the more current colloquial slang (if there is any) for some terms (eg. Androgynous, gender fluid, unisex/genderless, gender neutral). The reason I’d love to know some of these terms is because I’d like to actually use the simplified Chinese within my designs.

My family have recently moved to Shanghai and I live there when I’m not studying in the UK but I have to admit I have an appalling grasp on the language! While I guess I could ask people over there, I would never want to use language in my work that could be deemed offensive or derogatory and don't want to risk this happening, and I haven't found a lot of literature on the topic while searching the internet.

If you have any suggestions for me, I would hugely appreciate the help! Thank you so much in advance

Answer (score 4):

The Wikipedia page for [性别酷儿](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-cn/%E6%80%A7%E5%88%A5%E9%85%B7%E5%85%92) mentions:

> 性别酷儿（Genderqueer、gender-fluid、non-binary）

and also goes into specific definitions:

> - 非二元性别（Gender Queer，Gender non-binary）
> - 精神双性人（Bigender）
> - 精神三性人（Trigender）
> - 精神无性人（Agender）
> - 精神泛性人（Pangender）
> - 性别流体（Gender fluid）

---

[中性](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-cn/%E5%85%A9%E6%80%A7%E5%85%B1%E4%BA%AB) also works for gender neutral.

Answer (score 1):

男性 (male); 男性服装 (male clothing)

女性 (female); 女性服装 (female clothing)

中性 (unisex); 中性服装 (unisex clothing)

other choices:

男女皆宜的/ 男女合适的 (for men or women)